# HTML Video playback on Chrome causing CSS glitch with background color

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html5-video

I have an issue where when I play back a normal HTML video with this code:

```
<video src="http:/s...." width="100%" height="100%" controls loop muted playsInline preload="auto" >
</video>
```

It causes weird rendering issues in the background of my Navigation buttons as you can see here:

https://d.pr/i/xdhttM

When I pause the video, the background goes back to normal like this:

https://d.pr/i/JhGnCz

As you can see, there is no more weird line going across.

Now I have also tested it, and I realized that it only happens on divs with a linear gradient. I have a gradient that looks like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(91.66deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) -24.62%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03) 167.43%);
backdrop-filter: blur(17.5px);
```

If I remove the gradient, it's all good.

This issue only happens on Chrome.